# First picker row selection changes second picker row

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uipickerview

Ive picked up some code form another developer which im trying to put right.  One of the problems is:

I have 2 pickers that fill a text box with selected row from a picker.

If picker 1 (named: Type) is selected,  the row selected ..say row 3, defaults to that row on my next picker (named: FlueType) when the picker is presented.

How can I get the second picker not be affected by the first pickers row selection?

Ive looked at `[picker reloadComponent:0];` I've looked on stack and google and cant seem to find anything that fits this problem.

Ive also tried `[picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO]` in the ViewDidLoad method hoping that it would set all my pickers to the first row value which is all im trying to do.

Apologies for the mountain of code, I've tried to separate it out into context

```
      /////////////////////picker action////////////////////////

      -(void)flueTypeBtnClicked//:(id)sender
       {    

   [flueTypeBtn.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

currentSelectedIndex = flueTypeBtn.tag;
[makeTxt resignFirstResponder];
[modelTxt resignFirstResponder];
[locationTxt resignFirstResponder];
[oprPressureMBarTxt resignFirstResponder];

[picker setHidden:NO];
[picker reloadComponent:0];




[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
self.ToolsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 260);

extern GasCertificateAppViewController *viewController;
[viewController.view addSubview:self.ToolsView];


[UIView commitAnimations];
   }




 -(void)typeBtnClicked//:(id)sender
 {  

 [typeBtn.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];


currentSelectedIndex = typeBtn.tag;
[makeTxt resignFirstResponder];
[modelTxt resignFirstResponder];
[locationTxt resignFirstResponder];
[oprPressureMBarTxt resignFirstResponder];




[picker setHidden:NO];
[picker reloadComponent:0];

//NSLog(@"In type btn Clicked:");
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
self.ToolsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 260);
extern GasCertificateAppViewController *viewController;
[viewController.view addSubview:self.ToolsView];

    [UIView commitAnimations];


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////more code here///////////////////////


  - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {

if (textField.tag == 1 )
{
    [self typeBtnClicked];
    return NO;
}
else if(textField.tag == 3)
{
    [self flueTypeBtnClicked];
    return NO;
}

CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, textField.frame.origin.y - textField.frame.size.height);
[self.screenScrollView setContentOffset: offset animated: YES];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

self.ToolsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 260);
extern GasCertificateAppViewController *viewController;
[viewController.view addSubview:self.ToolsView];

[UIView commitAnimations];
    return YES;
   }


      //////////////

   -(void) fillData
  {
extern Survey *survey;
ApplianceTest *test = [survey.applianceTestArray objectAtIndex:testId];

if(test.type != nil)
    [self.typeTxt setText:test.type];
   // [self.typeBtn setTitle:test.type forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
if(test.make != nil)
    [self.makeTxt setText:test.make];
if(test.model != nil)
    [self.modelTxt setText:test.model];
if(test.location != nil)
    [self.locationTxt setText:test.location];
if(test.flue_type != nil)
    [self.flueTypeTxt setText:test.flue_type];
    //[self.flueTypeBtn setTitle:test.flue_type forState:UIControlStateNormal];    if(test.operating_pressure_mbar_or_heat_input_kwh != nil)
    [self.oprPressureMBarTxt setText:test.operating_pressure_mbar_or_heat_input_kwh];

if([test.safety_device_correct isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
    [self.segtCtrl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
else
    if([test.safety_device_correct isEqualToString:@"No"])
        [self.segtCtrl setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
        else
            [self.segtCtrl setSelectedSegmentIndex:2];


    }
   -(IBAction)bgTouched:(id)sender
     {        


CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[self.screenScrollView setContentOffset: offset animated: YES];[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

self.ToolsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 500, 320,260);
//[self.ToolsView removeFromSuperview];

//self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,  372 ); 

[makeTxt resignFirstResponder];
[modelTxt resignFirstResponder];
[locationTxt resignFirstResponder];
[oprPressureMBarTxt resignFirstResponder];


[UIView commitAnimations];
 }
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


   - (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

//segment control selected Index = 2;



segtCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex = 2;

navigationTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 0, 200, 25)];
navigationTitleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
navigationTitleLabel.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:18];
navigationTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
navigationTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
navigationTitleLabel.text = @"Appliance Test 1/3";

self.navigationItem.titleView = navigationTitleLabel;


self.screenScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 370);
self.screenScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 600 + 200);
self.screenScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.screenScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
[self.view addSubview:self.screenScrollView];   


testId = [testIdStr intValue];
currentSelectedIndex = 0;

typeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[typeArray addObject:@""]; ///change 
[typeArray addObject:@"Boiler"];
[typeArray addObject:@"Cooker"];
[typeArray addObject:@"Fire"];
[typeArray addObject:@"Hob"]; ///change to hob


currentSelectedIndex = 0;
flueTypeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[flueTypeArray addObject:@""]; //change
[flueTypeArray addObject:@"OF"];
[flueTypeArray addObject:@"RS"];
[flueTypeArray addObject:@"FL"];



unitArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"MBar",@"KW/h",nil];
//self.navigationItem.title = @"Appliance Test 1/3";

//[typeTableView setHidden:YES];
//[flueTypeTableView setHidden:YES];

[segtCtrl setSelectedSegmentIndex:2];

extern Survey *survey;


    [self fillData];
[picker setHidden:YES];
self.ToolsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 500, 320, 260);

  /////////////////

    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    {
return 1;
    }

  - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:    (NSInteger)component
   {
if (currentSelectedIndex == 1)
{
    return [typeArray count];
}
else if(currentSelectedIndex == 3)
{
    return [flueTypeArray count];
}
else if(currentSelectedIndex == 7)
{
    return [unitArray count];   
}
else
{
    return 1;
}
   }


  - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row   forComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
if (currentSelectedIndex == 1)
{
    if ([typeArray count] == 0)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"None"];

    }
    else
    {
    return [typeArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
else if(currentSelectedIndex == 3)
{
    if ([flueTypeArray count] == 0)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"None"];

    }
else {


        return [flueTypeArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
else if(currentSelectedIndex == 7)
{
    if ([unitArray count] == 0)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"None"];

    }
    else
    {
        return [unitArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
 return @"";

 }
 - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
//      [gasSafeNoBtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[(NSNumber *) [gasSafeNoArray objectAtIndex:row]intValue]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
extern Survey *survey;
if (currentSelectedIndex==1) 
{
    //typeTxt.text = [typeArray objectAtIndex:row];
    [typeBtn.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [typeBtn setTitle:[typeArray objectAtIndex:row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    typeTxt.text  =[typeArray objectAtIndex:row] ;
}
else if(currentSelectedIndex == 3)
{
    //flueTypeTxt.text = [flueTypeArray objectAtIndex:row];
    [flueTypeBtn.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [flueTypeBtn setTitle:[flueTypeArray objectAtIndex:row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    flueTypeTxt.text= [flueTypeArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
else if(currentSelectedIndex == 7)
{
    unitString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[unitArray objectAtIndex:row]];
//  NSLog(@"Unit String : %@", unitString);
    [unitBtn setTitle:[unitArray objectAtIndex:row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {

}

 }

 - (void)dealloc {
[unitArray release];
[ToolsView release];
[toolBar release];
[nextBtn release];
[prevBtn release];
[doneBtn release];
[picker release];
    [super dealloc];

   }


   @end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorted....added

`[picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO]`;

to the button action method presenting the picker